# chaning the color of pixel on touch ionic 3

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic3, angular5

Is there any way or method to **change pixel color** after getting screen **X-Y coordinate** without use of **canvas**? if so, Please help me with this.

Comment: in order to be more clear, put piece of your code that you are working on please.

Comment: i'm working on screen test app, I got X-Y point of mobile screen but i don't know how to mark something on that X-Y point without the use of canvas because if i'll use canvas then i'm not able to use any functionality.

Comment: If its mot via canvas then all else is a hack. Like you could “place” a 1px size div at the pixel location as overlay but not sure this helps your purpose.